# How to check from Parent component, how many times child component is being called

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<parent-component>
<child-component></child-component>
<child-component></child-component>
<child-component></child-component>
<child-component></child-component>
<parent-component>

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    inputs: [count]
})
```

I am calling components from parent component, and i would like to print how many times those child components called.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a service with a property to track the count. Then increment it in the ngOnInit of the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Let try with this way

parent-component.component.ts

```
class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childComponents: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.childComponents.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: @ViewChildren ??

Comment: @MithunSudheendran yes, you can ref to this document https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren